# How to use the `.loc` method from pandas on a custom class object?

Tags: python, pandas, class, object, indexing

I've been going through the source code of pandas https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py and I can't figure out where they actually implement the `.loc` slicing method.  I'm working on a wrapper that takes in a bunch of `pd.DataFrames`.  For the sake of this question, let's call it `DataFrameCollection`.  I don't want to inherit all of the methods so I don't want to do `class DataFrameCollection(pd.DataFrame): pass`.

**Does anyone know which code is responsible for the `.loc` method of a `pd.DataFrame` object and how this can be used on a custom object?**

Essentially I would like to be able to do the following:

```
dfc_iris =  DataFrameCollection(" a bunch of dataframes")
dfc_iris.loc[idx_obsvs, :]
```

Comment: See the [`_LocIndexer`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2d4dd508fa7419a39201ad7befb287d0d72378ef/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1545) class, and it being [added to `NDFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2d4dd508fa7419a39201ad7befb287d0d72378ef/pandas/core/generic.py#L10722-L10724).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `loc` attribute is one of several indexers, see the [`pandas.core.indexing` module](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py), specifically the [`get_indexers_list()` function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/indexing.py#L30-L39):

```
# the supported indexers
def get_indexers_list():


    return [
        ('ix', _IXIndexer),
        ('iloc', _iLocIndexer),
        ('loc', _LocIndexer),
        ('at', _AtIndexer),
        ('iat', _iAtIndexer),
    ]
```

Each of those classes is defined in the same module.

That function [is used to add attributes to the `NDFrame` class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/generic.py#L10731-L10733), which is a base class of `pandas.DataFrame`. Each of the classes in the `get_indexers_list()` result is [added as a `property` object](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/generic.py#L2822-L2827).

So to re-use the object type, you could add your properties, using the same code if necessary; add the same class method to your class

```
@classmethod
def _create_indexer(cls, name, indexer):
    """Create an indexer like _name in the class."""
    if getattr(cls, name, None) is None:
        _indexer = functools.partial(indexer, name)
        setattr(cls, name, property(_indexer, doc=indexer.__doc__))
```

then add the indexers with

```
# install the indexes
for _name, _indexer in indexing.get_indexers_list():
    DataFrameCollection._create_indexer(_name, _indexer)
```

Given a `dfcollection` instance of your `DataFrameCollection` class,  `dfcollection.loc` would then result in `_LocIndexer('loc', dfcollection)` being called and returned.

Do study the remaining code in `pandas.core.indexing` to see how each indexer then expects to find information on your `DataFrameCollection` instance; it's the `self.obj` reference in the indexer methods.

For example, `dfcollection.loc[...]` is translated to [`_LocationIndexer.__getitem__()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1488-L1503), which delegates to [`_LocIndexer._is_scalar_access()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1804-L1826), [`_LocIndexer._getitem_scalar()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1828-L1832), [`_NDFrameIndexer._getitem_tuple()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/indexing.py#L868-L892) and [`_LocIndexer._getitem_axis()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/db2066b7d31450aaa87f2efcef492162a3d08309/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1858-L1916), which together with methods these delegate to, need access to *at least* the `.axes`, `.ndim` `._get_value()`, `._get_axis_name()`, `._get_axis_number()`, `._get_axis()`, `._reindex_with_indexers()` and `._take()` attributes and methods on the dataframe.